# Removing background space from vector assets in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, vector

I keep trying to create a vector for a simple hexagon in various different SVG editing programs, making sure the edges of the vector hug the edges of the field.  However, after inputting it into android studio it adds about a width of the actual hexagon in background space to each side, creating something that I can't move around or align correctly.  I was wondering if there was any way to fix this directly in the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportWidth="612"
    android:viewportHeight="792">

    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M241.1,395.1c0,-11.3 0.1,-22.7 -0.1,-34c0,-3.1 1,-4.6 3.7,-6.1c10.5,-5.8 20.7,-11.9 31.1,-17.9c8.8,-5.1 17.6,-10.1 26.4,-15.2c5.5,-3.1 9.4,1 13.5,3.3c17.6,10 35,20.2 52.5,30.3c2.6,1.5 3.9,3.1 3.8,6.2c-0.1,22.6 0,45.3 -0.2,67.9c0,1.8 -1.3,4.3 -2.8,5.2c-20.2,11.9 -40.6,23.7 -61,35.3c-1.3,0.8 -4,0.4 -5.4,-0.4c-19.8,-11.4 -39.5,-22.9 -59,-34.6c-1.4,-0.8 -2.5,-3.3 -2.6,-5C241,418.5 241.1,406.8 241.1,395.1zM364.1,395.9c0,-9.8 -0.1,-19.7 0.1,-29.5c0.1,-3 -0.7,-4.7 -3.5,-6.3c-17.2,-9.7 -34.2,-19.7 -51.3,-29.3c-1.5,-0.8 -4.2,-1.2 -5.6,-0.4c-18,10.1 -35.9,20.5 -53.8,30.9c-1.1,0.6 -1.8,2.7 -1.8,4.1c-0.1,20.2 -0.1,40.3 0,60.5c0,1.4 1.1,3.5 2.3,4.2c17.8,10.5 35.6,20.9 53.5,31.2c1.1,0.6 3,0.6 4.1,0.1c3.3,-1.5 6.4,-3.5 9.5,-5.3c14,-8.3 27.9,-16.8 42.2,-24.6c3.5,-1.9 4.4,-3.7 4.4,-7.1C364,414.9 364.1,405.4 364.1,395.9z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#f51717" android:pathData="M364.1,395.9c0,9.5 -0.1,19 0,28.5c0,3.5 -0.9,5.2 -4.4,7.1c-14.3,7.8 -28.2,16.3 -42.2,24.6c-3.1,1.8 -6.2,3.8 -9.5,5.3c-1.1,0.5 -3,0.5 -4.1,-0.1c-17.9,-10.3 -35.7,-20.7 -53.5,-31.2c-1.2,-0.7 -2.3,-2.8 -2.3,-4.2c-0.1,-20.2 -0.1,-40.3 0,-60.5c0,-1.4 0.7,-3.5 1.8,-4.1c17.8,-10.5 35.8,-20.8 53.8,-30.9c1.4,-0.8 4.1,-0.4 5.6,0.4c17.2,9.7 34.2,19.7 51.3,29.3c2.8,1.6 3.5,3.3 3.5,6.3C364,376.2 364.1,386 364.1,395.9z"/>

</vector>
```

Fixed it:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportWidth="173.2"
    android:viewportHeight="200">

    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M 86.6 0 L 173.2 50 V 150 L 86.6 200 L 0 150 V 50 L 86.6 0 z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#ffffff" android:pathData="M 86.6 10 L 164.54 55 V 145 L 86.6 190 L 8.66 145 V 55 L 86.6 10 z"/>


</vector>
```

Comment: you have to adjust `android:viewportWidth` and `viewportHeight` to your hexagon bounds and also move both paths to 0,0 origin

Comment: for example using inkscape: https://pastebin.com/raw/xpPes5kh

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to import yours, so I researched how to manually code vectors using the XML.  Thank you for your help though!  Your first comment was the only reason I figured it out.

Comment: just save it as a svg file, you can edit it with inkscape for example or directly import in android studio

Comment: Oh, I have it working now, my code is much simpler now: